# Access to the additional information about users

Tags: django

I have read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) and I have one question. How to take access to the 'other fields'?

**models:**

```
class UsersProfile(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.last_name
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    car_num = models.IntegerField('car ID')
    captain = models.BooleanField()
```

**views:**

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

So, after authentication, in profile works only **user.last_login** + etc, but not **user.car_num** or **user.captain**. I read about **get_profile()**, but where I need it to write?

```
profile = request.user.get_profile()
```

If it in views, how to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `related_name` for your `OneToOneField`, like this:

```
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
```

and then access the corresponding fields using

```
request.user.profile.car_num
```